# What is the best way to learn VFX?

Tags: editing, software-recommendation, premiere-elements, visual-effects

I am new to this field but I'm very interested in making VFX and I had done some VFX clips on my phone. But I want some software names which I can understand easily and also create visual effects.

Comment: I disagree that is a dupe. They are different questions. One is how to learn. Another is which tool to use.

Answer (score 1):

VFX on a phone is much different than actually doing it on a computer. You might want to take stepping stones to VFX and start by editing videos with a NLE. One of my favorites is Premiere Pro (though, it's been buggy lately). Once you learn how to edit videos, you can then move onto VFX with Adobe After Effects, or Hitfilm for more simpler stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[I assume you have some experience in video editing, if you don't you MIGHT struggle with vfx]

Adobe After effects is probably the easiest yet very powerful vfx software. It is layer based as opposed to node base so it will be easier to learn and understand. It might not be as powerful and flexible but it will more than you need when starting out. One of the best tutorial site for After effects is www.videocopilot.net .

If you want some more recommendation of softwares, here is a short list: 
Adobe After effects, 
The Foundry Nuke(use commonly in the industry), 
BlackMagic fusion(use commonly in the industry), Fitfilm(all in one solution, cheap, not used in the industry)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know editing to start making Vfx although it doesn't hurt to have some editing experience. It depends on what you are aiming for when learning Vfx. After effects is predominantly used in TV visual effects and motion graphics, while more complex visual effects tend to use software like fusion, nuke etc.pp.

How to start learning this? There is around 1 million tutorials on YouTube so why don't you just pick something you want to do and start following a tutorial about it. If you want to have an idea how things are done, watch some behind the scenes for Vfx heavy movies...